# How to create a circular array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a circular reference to array. For example,

`float arr1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

Then I use a variable in loop to access elements of array.

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<arr1[i]<<std::endl;
    //other processing using arr1[i] indexing
}
```

Here, I can only use `i<=10`. If I want to make `i<=16` and if `i>10` then index should go to `arr1[0]` and proceed from there. What are preferable or recommended ways to do this?

Comment: Modulo operator

Comment: With your condition `i <= 10` you will access the eleventh element of the ten-element array.

Comment: I would provide an iterator that increments such that `++(end-1)==begin`

Comment: By using [`Boost.Circular Buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html). Otherwise, by reading that and understanding how it works.

Comment: Alternatively have a linked list with the last element's next pointer pointing to the first element.

Comment: You could pop the for loop into a while loop and go through it as many times as needed.

Comment: @hellyale, I didn't get how to pop for loop to while and it will enable me to get around the problem

Comment: @Ðаn, What is wrong with using plain array?

Comment: @Ðаn also curious what is wrong with an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the modulo operator `%`. 
`14 % 10 = 4` So just do this with the index you use to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like @Jdman1699 said the modulo operator. Here you find an example:

```
int position; //the position you want to get
float out = arr1[position%10];
```

Answer (score -1):

For your *specific* program, I would simply suggest putting your base for loop inside of another for loop (as it seems that you want to print out all elements of the array many times over, considering your source code). This is because accessing element *n* is no different than accessing element *n + 10*. However, if you are planning to create some sort of function to access *any* element of the array, I would use the modulo operator-base 10. Maybe,

```
unsigned long int newidx = iptidx%10;
```

and then work with newidx.

Answer (score -2):

**May be u r looking for...**

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<arr1[i%10]<<std::endl;
    //other processing using arr1[i] indexing
}
```

Comment: Please use full words and sentences; you are not on Instagram now.